# Unresolved external symbol (with RAII)

Tags: c++

***This question is solved, just re-add the cpp file with the implementations to the project.***

I am currently working on a Timer with RAII functionality and I came across an 'unresolved external symbol' error for both constructor and destructor. 
Am I missing something?

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include "File.h"

int main()
{
    RAIITimer timer;
    File f{"test.txt", true};
    for(int i{1000000}; i > 0; i--)
    {
        f.write("example\n");
    }
}
```

**Timer.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <chrono>

#include "Types.h"

using hr_clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

class RAIITimer
{
public:
    RAIITimer(conststrref name = "Test");
    ~RAIITimer();

private:
    hr_clock::time_point m_start;
    hr_clock::time_point m_end;
    std::string m_name;
};
```

**Timer.cpp:**

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include "OutUtils.h"

using std::chrono::milliseconds;

RAIITimer::RAIITimer(conststrref name)
    :   m_name  {name}
{
    m_start = hr_clock::now();
}

RAIITimer::~RAIITimer()
{
    m_end = hr_clock::now();
    double duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(m_end - m_start).count();
    logging::log(m_name + " finished in " + std::to_string(duration) + "ms");
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Silly question but... are you sure that timer.cpp is being compiled by your project?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, since I can "exclude it from the project". Any other way to check this?

Comment: Ok, you were right....I removed it and readded it. Seemed to be a bug. Thanks for the help, dude! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, and don't add "Solved" to the title. The way to indicate that your question has been answered is to accept an answer.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: That would have to wait 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems to be a current bug with Visual Studio. All I had to do, was to re-add the file to my project. Thanks to Jorge Y!